# lwuit wizard and deploy

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit, codenameone

I am developing J2ME application with lwuit and Codenameone and created it in lots of time. After I created it I wanted to deploy it in some devices like Nokia, Samsung, LG and etc. that they supported MIDP. So I figure out Nokia devices run it with no error and Samsung and other companies devices have some problems that I can't understand why?!

So I tried different way of creating this application. I used Codenameone wizard with blank theme and manual template and then I tried to deploy it. Well, that right. I got success and it ran in Samsung devices too.
After that I tried to add some forms to "theme" in this appliaction and run it in simulator. I changed some code in my main class like this:

```
public class Main extends UIBuilder {

private Form current;

public void init(Object context) {
    try{
        Resources theme = Resources.openLayered("/theme");
        UIManager.getInstance().setThemeProps(theme.getTheme(theme.getThemeResourceNames()[0]));
   }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void start() {
    if(current != null){
        current.show();
        return;
    }
Form hi = findMain();//new Form("Hi World");
//hi.addComponent(new Label("Hi World"));
hi.show();
}

public void stop() {
    current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
}

public void destroy() {
}

public com.codename1.ui.Form findMain() {
    return (com.codename1.ui.Form)findByName("Main", Display.getInstance().getCurrent());
}}
```

I got error when I ran it.

So this is my questions:
I created one application in Visual Mode of Codenameone.
How can I run it in Samsung and some other devices like Samsung (without opertaing system, just support java or MIDP)?
How can I change my Visual Mode application to Manual Mode in Codenameone?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are deriving from `UIBuilder` within the lifecycle class and trying to use a finder method on something that isn't showing yet. There is absolutely no way that your code works in the simulator and it is not the code that was generated by the wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Shai. For creating I did hard coding and create all of forms one by one.

I implement base Form that derive from `com.codenameone.ui.Form` and every forms derive from base Form.